# Is there a way with ssmtp to include a file as the body?

Tags: files, input, ssmtp

With ssmtp, is there a way to include a file as just the body?

I would like to send as below so I can just email myself something:

```
$ ssmtp me@gmail.com
To: me
From: me
Subject: A File

< fileName
Ctrl + D
```

I've tried this, but only "< fileName" gets emailed, not the file.

I don't want to have to open a file and prepend To:, From:, Subject:, and then delete this from the file after it arrives.

I know I can do just:

```
ssmtp me@gmail.com <fileName
Ctrl + D
```

But this leaves the Subject, To, and From fields blank in my email client.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    echo To: me@gmail.com
    echo From: from@gmail.com
    echo Subject: A file
    echo
    find /dir/to/folder/ -type f -size +1M -name "fileName"
} | ssmtp me@gmail.com
```

Comment: This works great! I just replaced the find command with "cat fileName" for less typing. If there's not a more concise solution in the next few days I'll vote your reply as the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Rinzwind, thanks for the inspiration. Here's what I've come up with.
I put this in my .bash_aliases file:

```
alias email='{ 
echo To: Kevin;
echo From: Kevin;
echo Subject: Subject;
echo;
cat FILE;
} | ssmtp myEmailAddress'
```

To run this I type:

```
$ email
(Then I press Ctrl + Alt + E)
```

to bring up the command without executing it.
Then I edit FILE or anything else I want and then press Enter.

It also works to add just a prompt for a filename when always sending to myself:

```
alias email='{ 
echo To: Kevin;
echo From: Kevin;
echo Subject: Subject;
echo;
read -p "Enter filename: " fileName;
cat $fileName;
} | ssmtp myEmailAddress'
```

In this case, I don't press Ctrl + Alt + E. I just press Enter, then give the filename and press Enter again.

Of course I would use a different alias for one of these if I used both, but the first one is more versatile so I use it.

Fun!